# Modal focus on div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

You guys are probably aware of the jQuery Dialog modal option (sample: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

I would like to do something similar, but not in a popup. I would like to show focus on a part of my website to the user, and this focus would disappear if he presses a button.

If you take this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwfVk/1/

```
<div id="box1" style="background-color:red">
    Content
</div>

<div id="box2" style="background-color:green">
    Content
</div>

<div id="box3" style="background-color:blue">
    Content
</div>
```

I would like the page to have focus on the green part and everything else would be gray. The same kind of gray we have with modal dialog. In my website the user would click on a button and the gray "modal" would then disappear. No need to prevent users to left click out of the focus, I look only for the visual effect.

Is there a hidden function in jQuery that I am not aware of?

Comment: something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/qwfVk/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/qwfVk/3/ .. with close button http://jsfiddle.net/qwfVk/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may in CSS use focus and or target.**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qwfVk/23/)**

Focus, to be able to be catch by `div`, needs to be emulated via `tabindex` attribute:
example :

```
<p>
click here
<a href="#box1">box1</a>
<a href="#box2">box2</a>
<a href="#box1">box3</a>
or onto the box:
</p>
<div id="box1" tabindex="0" style="background-color:#ff0000;padding:4px;border-radius:5px;">text.<a href="#none">close</a></div>
<br />
<div id="box2" tabindex="0" style="background-color:#00ff00;padding:4px;border-radius:5px;">text.<a href="#none">close</a></div>
<br />
<div id="box3" tabindex="0" style="background-color:#00aaff;padding:4px;border-radius:5px;">text.<a href="#none">close</a></div>
```

and basic CSS :

```
div:target, div:focus {
    position:relative;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 5000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
a {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    background:white
}
```

Comment: The CSS style position:relative; box-shadow:0 0 0 5000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); completly answer my question. I can now play with this :). However you should update your demo because your box3 link point to the id="box1" instead of id="box3".